# Custom fact does not receive value

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

This is a playbook part of a role that talks with vmware.
I'm is trying to set a custom fact <kbd>(target_vm)</kbd> that receive the virtual machine name.
But when I Print it's value with the **debug** module it apears to be empty.
I don't know what I'm is doing wrong in the **set_fact** module.

This is the Playbook

```
- delegate_to: localhost
  become: no
  delegate_facts: yes
  vars:
    vc_hostname: 'vcenter.bio.local'
    vc_username: 'bio.local\ansible'
    vc_password: "{{ v_pass }}"
    vm_uuid: '4217200F-46D2-C9FD-E7FD-768D21B327E8' | lower
  block:
    - name: Gather only registered virtual machines
      vmware_vm_info:
        hostname: '{{ vc_hostname }}'
        username: '{{ vc_username }}'
        password: '{{ vc_password }}'
        validate_certs: False
        vm_type: vm
      delegate_to: localhost
      register: virtual_info
      no_log: true

    - name: Set facts target_vm when equal vm-name
      set_fact:
        target_vm: "{{ my_item.guest_name }}"
      with_items: "{{ virtual_info.virtual_machines }}"
      when: my_item.uuid == vm_uuid
      loop_control:
        loop_var: my_item


    - name: Print Guest Name
      debug:
        msg:
          - "{{ foo_item.guest_name }}"
          - "{{ target_vm | default ('') }}"
      with_items: "{{ virtual_info.virtual_machines }}"
      when: foo_item.uuid == vm_uuid
      loop_control:
        loop_var: foo_item
```

This is the output

```
TASK [vmwaretaks : Gather only registered virtual machines] ***********************************************************************************************
ok: [testvm]

TASK [vmwaretaks : Set facts target_vm when equal vm-name] ************************************************************************************************
ok: [testvm] => (item={'guest_name': 'TESTVM', 'guest_fullname': 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 (64-bit)', 'power_state': 'poweredOn', 'ip_address': '192.168.54.32', 'mac_address': ['00:32:52:97:e9:c8'], 'uuid': '4217200f-46d2-c9fd-e7fd-768d21b327e8', 'vm_network': {'00:32:52:97:e9:c8': {'ipv4': ['192.168.54.32'], 'ipv6': ['fe80::250:56ff:fe97:d4c3']}}, 'esxi_hostname': 'b3j15esx05.bio.local', 'cluster': 'JAS-Lab-DEP', 'attributes': {}, 'tags': []})

TASK [vmwaretaks : Print Guest Name] **********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [testvm] => (item={'guest_name': 'TESTVM', 'guest_fullname': 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 (64-bit)', 'power_state': 'poweredOn', 'ip_address': '192.168.54.32', 'mac_address': ['00:32:52:97:e9:c8'], 'uuid': '4217200f-46d2-c9fd-e7fd-768d21b327e8', 'vm_network': {'00:32:52:97:e9:c8': {'ipv4': ['192.168.54.32'], 'ipv6': ['fe80::250:56ff:fe97:d4c3']}}, 'esxi_hostname': 'b3j15esx05.bio.local', 'cluster': 'JAS-Lab-DEP', 'attributes': {}, 'tags': []}) => {
    "msg": [
        "TESTVM",
        ""
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************
testvm              : ok=13   changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=2    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

As you can see the second message that prints the target_vm var output is empty
Hope you can help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have changed the way I parse the guest_name in the set_fact and had a progress but stills debug module don't prints the target_vm.

Comment: `- name: Set facts target_vm when equal vm-name
  set_fact:
    target_vm: "{{ my_item['guest_name'] }}"
  with_items: "{{ virtual_info.virtual_machines }}"
  when: my_item.uuid == vm_uuid
  loop_control:
    loop_var: my_item`

Comment: `TASK [vmwaretaks : Set facts target_vm when equal vm-name] *************************************************************************
ok: [testvm] => (item={'guest_name': 'TESTVM', 'guest_fullname': 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 (64-bit)', 'power_state': 'poweredOn', 'ip_address': '192.168.54.32', 'mac_address': ['00:32:52:97:e9:c8'], 'uuid': '4217200f-46d2-c9fd-e7fd-768d21b327e8', 'vm_network': {'00:32:52:97:e9:c8': {'ipv4': ['192.168.54.32']}}, 'esxi_hostname': 'b3j15esx05.bio.local', 'cluster': 'JAS-Lab-DEP', 'attributes': {}, 'tags': []}) => {"ansible_facts": {"target_vm": "TESTVM"}...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. It seems the fact is set with its value but I don't handle to print it correctly so I will expose the question again on other post.